# Custom Module layout xml not working?

Tags: magento2, module, layout, xml, phtml

I've created a custom module that holds a simple phtml file, block class to include elements into the phtml file and a default.xml within my Module/view/frontend/layout.

However I am struggling to add my phtml to my page using the default.xml within my module, however I can add this using the default.xml within my theme.

Heres the contents of my xml within my module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="autosmart.logo" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <block class="Autosmart\DistributorSearch\Block\DistributorSearch" name="distributor.search" template="distributor-search.phtml"></block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Do I need to do anything to use this module default.xml rather than having to add my phtml to the page using my theme default.xml?

Answer (score 1):

The template should be `Autosmart_DistributorSearch::path/to/distributor-search.phtml`

Please note that the `template` parameter starts from `Autosmart/DistributorSearch/view/frontend/templates`

Comment: My phtml file is within Autosmart/DistributorSearch/view/frontend/templates and the coding is exactly the same within my theme default xml which is working?

Comment: Yes, you should put the template file under `Autosmart/DistributorSearch/view/frontend/templates`. Of course, you can create and directories as you want, just pointing to the right file is OK. If still doesn't work, check if the module is enabled and clear cache.

Comment: Module is enabled and I have cleared cache, the issue I am having is that I cannot add this to the page from the xml in my module, but I can in my theme default.xml using the same coding? Do I need to do anything to tell magento to run my xml in my module?

Comment: have you fixed this @heady12 i am facing the same issue